# Jira Development - Agile Project configuration under version 7.1.7 of Jira

Tags: jira, scrum, jql, jira-agile, scrumboard

I´m writing because it´s been really difficult to understand the Jira Development Environment, given that there are many differences between 6.x and 7.x versions and the documentations not always is accurate, as far as I could see as a starter in this platform.

**I´d like to know if someone can help me to create an agile project in Jira (v.7.1.7) under a development environment, and there, I´ll start to test the code I´m writting as scripts for Script Runner.**

I installed everything to develop as explained [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project/set-up-the-sdk-prerequisites-on-a-windows-system).

The server I´m running is started with:
**atlas-run-standalone --product jira**

or

**atlas-run** when I start to write something in the plugin development. I use this the most.

Jira is opened through: 
http://localhost:2990/jira/

The version of jira says: v7.1.7

When I try to create a project, jira offers only the business kind of projects (project management, task management, process management), but I need the software kind of projects, or at least the scrum projects, because I´m developing a small piece of code that requires epics, stories and scrum oriented concepts, which are not present in the projects I can create right now.

Any ideas about this problem? Does someone know why I can´t create agile projects in my server if the plugin of jira agile must be installed by default in the 7.x version of jira?

Thanks in advance for any help or orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received an answer from the Jira Team.

"... when JIRA is up and running, please go to Admin > Applications section and install JIRA Software (Agile) part of JIRA. It brings all development extensions..."

I didn´t know that had to be activated in the version 7 of Jira. There, I could find the Agile package.

Answer (score 0):

JIRA has a lot of history and it shows in its documentation. I'll try to give some pointers.

[This page](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/preparing-for-jira-7-0/jira-7-0-api-changes) lists the API changes between JIRA 6 and 7.

Because JIRA 7 introduced different applications (core, software, service desk) this also means that the API to create projects changed:

- You now have to [specify a project type when you create a project](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/preparing-for-jira-7-0/jira-7-0-api-changes#JIRA7.0-APIchanges-projecttypes).
- The [validation/creation of projects](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/preparing-for-jira-7-0/jira-7-0-api-changes#JIRA7.0-APIchanges-projectcreationapi) has changed.

Also, if you want to get access to the jira-software api sources in your IDE, then you need to add the appropriate dependencies to your pom. This is described [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configure-amps-to-run-jira-core-with-additional-applications-installed).

[This page](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis) lists all the available api documentation (both REST and java) for the different applications.

The JIRA Software API documentation is available [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/6.7.12/). At the time of writing, 6.7.12 is the latest JIRA Software version. That API also contains an additional service to create projects. Look at [ProjectService](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/6.7.12/com/atlassian/greenhopper/service/project/ProjectService.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was useful.